# UPDATE en una tabla relacionada a otra con PHP

Tags: php, mysql, login, update

Estoy tratando de realizar un update en una tabla que se relaciona  con otra. La tabla que estoy tratando de actualizar la denomine Login, ahí mismo tiene una llave foránea "tipousuario" ya que depende del tipo de usuario que se logueara.

El punto es que implemente la sentencia SQL en mi base de datos, actualiza bien pero al momento de hacerlo mediante PHP no genera la actualización.

```
<?php
    require 'Login.php';

    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
        $datos = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
        $respuesta = Registro::ActualizarDatoS($datos["id"],$datos["usuario"],$datos["password"],$datos["tipoUsuario"]);
        if($respuesta){
            echo "Se ha actualizado los datos correctamente";
        }else{
            echo "El usuario no esta registrado";
        }
    }
?>



<?php

require 'Database.php';

    class Registro{
        function _construct(){
        }
        public static function ObtenerUsuarios(){
            $consultar = "SELECT * FROM Login";
                $resultado = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consultar);
                $resultado->execute();
                $tabla = $resultado->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $tabla;
        }

        public static function ObtenerUsuarioID($id){
            $consultar = "SELECT id,usuario,password,tipoUsuario FROM Login WHERE id=?";
            try{
                $resultado = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consultar);
                $resultado->execute(array($id));
                $tabla = $resultado->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                return $tabla;
                }catch(PDOException $e){
                    return false;
            }
        }

        public static function InsertarNuevoDato ($id,$usuario,$password,$tipoUsuario){
            $consultar = "INSERT INTO Login(id,usuario,password,tipoUsuario) VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
            try{
                $resultado = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consultar);
                return $resultado->execute(array($id,$usuario,$password,$tipoUsuario));
            }catch(PDOException $e){
                return false;
            }
        }

        public static function ActualizarDatos ($id,$usuario,$password,$tipoUsuario){
            if(self::ObtenerUsuarioID($id)){
                $consultar = "UPDATE Login INNER JOIN TipoUsuario ON Login.tipoUsuario=TipoUsuario.id  SET Login.usuario=?,Login.password=?,Login.tipoUsuario=? WHERE Login.id=?";
                $resultado = Database::getInstance()->getDb()->prepare($consultar);
                return $resultado->execute(array($id,$usuario,$password,$tipoUsuario));
            }else{
                return false;
            }
        }

    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A primera vista parecen estar en el orden equivocado los parámetros del método [execute()](http://php.net/manual/es/pdostatement.execute.php),

El `$id` debe ir al final ya que se asignará en esta parte de la consulta `WHERE Login.id=?`

Recordar que cuando se usan marcadores *(sin nombre)* , se deben respetar los parámetros en el orden en el que deberían ir en su `query`.

```
return $resultado->execute(array($usuario,$password,$tipoUsuario,$id));
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, se me pasaba ese detalle. Es increíble como se te puede pasar esas pequeñeces